# Static with classes error

Tags: c++, oop, polymorphism

this its C++.

i dont really know wheres the problem since the both of the static cast are equally typed but it only display correctly employee info, when it comes to patient info it only display date in and date out, but no person info, (employee does correctly print person info)

```
  void *print( ){
        Node *aux;
        aux = this->head;
        while(aux){
            Employee *employee = static_cast<Employee*>(aux->getPerson());
            Patient *patient = static_cast<Patient*>(aux->getPerson());
            if(employee) {
                employee->info();
            }
            else if (patient){
                patient->info();
                //Should be one of the cases above
            }
            aux = aux->getNext();
        }
        return 0;
```

just at the moment i print this, it prints only employee info but patient info its not displayed.

```
class Patient: public Person {

private:
int Id_Patient;
Person person;
string Date_In;
string Date_Out;

public:
    Patient(){
        this->Date_In;
        this->Date_Out;
    }
    Patient (int Id_Patient, Person person){
        this->Id_Patient=Id_Patient;
        this->person=person;
    }
    Patient (int Id_Patient, Person person, string Date_In, string Date_Out){
        this->Id_Patient=Id_Patient;
        this->Date_Out=Date_Out;
        this->Date_In=Date_In;
    }
    void setId_Patient(int Id_Patient){
        this->Id_Patient=Id_Patient;}
    int getId_Patient(){
        return this->Id_Patient;}

    void setDate_In(string Date_In){
        this->Date_In=Date_In;}
    string getDate_In(){
        return this->Date_In;}

    void setDate_Out(string Date_Out){
        this->Date_Out=Date_Out;}
    string getDate_Out(){
        return this->Date_Out;} 

    void setPerson(Person person) {
        this->person=person;    }       
    Person getPerson() {
        return this->person;}       

    void info() {
        cout <<"=================================" << endl; 
        cout << "Patient ID: " << this->Id_Patient << endl;
        this->person.info();
        cout << "Date_In: " << this->Date_In << endl;
        cout << "Date_Out: "<< this->Date_Out << endl;
        cout <<"=================================" << endl; 
    }
```

}; //clase patient

```
class Employee: public Person {
private:
    int Employee_Code;
    Person person;
    double Salary;
public:
    Employee() {
        this->Employee_Code;
        this->Salary;}

    Employee(int Employee_Code, Person person){
        this->Employee_Code=Employee_Code;
        this->person=person;
    }
    Employee(int Employee_Code, double Salary){
        this->Employee_Code=Employee_Code;
        this->Salary=Salary;
    }
    Employee(int Employee_Code, Person person, double Salary){
        this->Employee_Code=Employee_Code;
        this->person=person;
        this->Salary=Salary;
    }   
    void setEmployee_Code(int Employee_Code){
        this->Employee_Code=Employee_Code;}
    int getEmployee_Code(){
        return this->Employee_Code;}

    void setSalary(double Salary){
        this->Salary=Salary;}
    double getSalary(){
        return this->Salary;}

    void setPerson(Person person) {
        this->person=person;    }       
    Person getPerson() {
        return this->person;}   

    void info() {
        cout <<"=================================" << endl; 
        cout << "Employee_Code: " << this->Employee_Code << endl;
        this->person.info();
        cout << "Salary: " << this->Salary << endl;
        cout <<"=================================" << endl; 
    }
```

}; //clase employee

Answer (score 1):

It appears that OP has confused [`static_cast`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_cast) with [`dynamic_cast`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dynamic_cast). But there is a much better way to do this that eliminates the need for any casting: add pure virtual method `virtual void info()=0;` to `Person`.

`Patient` and `Employee`'s  `info` will implement `Person`'s `info` and `print` can simply

```
aux->getPerson()->info();
```

All done.

off topic, what point is there to returning `void *` from `print`? `void *` is a failure of imagination, bad planning, or an interface with a C library in C++. You should almost never use it, and certainly not to `return 0`.

Comment: thank you very much, virtual void on person fixed the problem, i throught i needed the return but i deleted it and it worked perfect. also, tried aux->getPerson()->info(); and it compiled wrong,                                                            [Error] cannot dynamic_cast 'aux->Node::getPerson()->Person::info()' (of type 'void') to type 'class Employee*' (source is not a pointer)                              and  [Error] void value not ignored as it ought to be @user4581301

Comment: Not entirely sure what all of that comment means, @EduardoGonzalez . I think it means is you  `Employee *employee = dynamic_cast<Employee*>(aux->getPerson()->info());`, and that's not required. The whole `while` loop becomes: `while(aux){ aux->getPerson()->info(); aux = aux->getNext(); }`